# What happened to super strength of Rohit?

Tags: movie, krrish, koi-mil-gaya

In the end of *Koi Mil Gaya*, it was displayed that *Jadoo* returned powers to Rohit which made him physically & mentally strong (than any human on Earth) again.

In *Krrish* (sequel of *Koi Mil Gaya*), Rohit's mental abilities were extra-ordinary as expected, but his physical strength didn't look extra-ordinary. He was easily captured like an ordinary human. What really happened to his physical strength?

Comment: No familiar with this story, but my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: @Pureferret If you're interested to know story from overview level, check Wikipedia pages of "Koi Mil Gaya" and Krrish.

Comment: @SachinShekhar It never showed in movie that Rohit was easily captured  or not.So how can we get analyse it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Have you forgot how Doctor Siddhant Aryan beaten down Rohit badly just after destruction of computer?

Comment: @SachinShekhar ohh...i forgot...but by the way there is no canon explanation for this present in any site. As you know Bollywood movies never gives canon explanation at all for any errors. So i think this question will remain unanswered.